# Linux Centos Selenium Chromedriver error : ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: linux, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver

I have read many posts already about this problem and tested many proposals but anythings works.
Here is the error

```
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Here is my code :

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.6

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url='https://www.google.com'
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('–-no-sandbox')
option.add_argument('–-headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

google-chrome --version

```
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
```

chromedriver -v

```
ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})
```

which chromedriver

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

symlinks

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
ln -s /usr/local/bin/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

I am under Linux Centos7 logged as root (but I have put option --no-sandbox)

Thank you very much